# WSDL vs DLL. Which is better?

Tags: c#, dll, comparison, tcp, wsdl

I would like to create a reusable interface to transfer some proprietary   information over the TCP/IP connection. If given only the choice of either **Web Services** or **distributing a pre-compiled Assembly**, what are the pros and cons of using each? This is assuming that Windows OS is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>A WSDL is a Web Service Definition. Are you creating a Web Service? If so, then use a WSDL.</strike>

If not, supply the DLL.

Based on comments, the question is a comparison of Web Services Vs. Precompiled Assembly.

In that case, I would recommend looking at using WCF to provide a service with a Tcp Endpoint using binary serialization. Using that method, you won't have to distribute any assemblies and you'll get something that is fairly fast as well.

Comment: I am actually taking more into consideration. Such as WSDL is a slower implementation as compared to a DLL which makes use of TCP sockets. On the other hand, WSDL is more portable and can be used on Linux, Mac, etc.

Comment: WSDL isn't an implementation of anything. It's simply a definition language. It sounds like you're talking about Web Services vs. Distributing a pre-compiled Assembly. Am I right?

Comment: @Lopper - I would change the wording of the question to reflect that then.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the web service (WSDL) because as long as we agree on the interface, the way I implement it can change many times, or as my demands/resources change, without requiring the client to modify its assemblies (DLL) to benefit from those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is "use net.tcp WCF or build your own transfer", I would recommend using a net.tcp WCF service if you are running IIS 7.0. It's easy to implement and decouples your systems from each other. Also, binary serialization is handled free of charge.

If you are not running IIS 7.0, then you'll need to add code for continual scanning, and building a custom DLL / listener may make more sense.